# Surface integral of $f(\vec x) = z^2$

Tags: surface-integrals

Let $\vec x = (x,y,z)^T$ and $f(\vec x) = z^2$. Calculate the surface integral
$$
\int_{|\vec x| = \frac{1}{2}} f \, \, dO
$$

my solution :

$dO = r^2 sin(u) \, \, du \, dv$ and $f(\vec x) = z^2 = r^2 cos^2(u)$.

$$
\Rightarrow \int_{|\vec x| = \frac{1}{2}} f \, \, dO = \frac{1}{16}\int_{0}^{2 \pi}  \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(u) \cos^2(u) \, \, du \, dv = \cdots 
$$
is the solution correct?

Thank you :)

Comment: yes, it is correct.

Comment: Super, Thank you  :)